# jQuery to find closest table under a div tag

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, find

I am trying to find the table headers using jQuery. This is what I tried but I couldn't get it working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var str = "FinalDate"; //change this based on col header 

    var today = new Date();
    //today = Date.parse(today)/1000;


        var a=0;

    var headers = $($(ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv).closest('table')+":first> tbody> tr:first th").get();


    $.each(headers, function(i,e){
        x = $(e).contents().find("a[title*='"+str+"']").length;
alert("X :"+x);
//x=3;

        a = x > 0 && i > a ? i : a;
alert("A :"+a);
//a=3;


    });
    var dArray = $($(ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv).closest('table')+":first> tbody> tr:gt(0)").find(">td:eq("+a+")").get()

  var dArray2 = $("table.ms-listviewtable:first> tbody> tr:gt(0)").find(">td:eq(4)").get()

$.each(dArray, function(i,e){
alert("i "+i+" e "+e);
        var d1 = $(e).text();

           $.each(dArray2, function(i,e){
        $(e).text(today);
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

What I am trying to achieve is read value in expected date and according set `FinalDate`. But I am unable to get the headers and than iterate through the same. Can anybody please help?

The below image shows the results I achieved using hardcoding index values.

[image]

Comment: `.closest()` will traverse the DOM tree upwards, not downwards. If you want to find content downwards, you should use `.find()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$($(ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv).find("table:first");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var headers = $(ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv).find('table:first>tbody>tr:first>th').get(0)
```

TRy above

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv').children('table').first();
```

Comment: this is better than find(); i guess it will traverse the DOM tree instead of a search operation

Comment: I used this and i get `var headers= $('#ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv').children('table').first();
alert("header"+headers)
 $.each(headers, function(i,e){
var t=$($(headers)+"td:contains('ExpectedDate')").index();` and i get the index as 37

Comment: @Ishan post another question for it after answering this one. what is ExpectedDate ? an attribute of <TD> tag

Comment: Index 37 is incorrect. It should be `3`. As can be seen in the image in my question `ExpectedDate` id one of the td attribute. Firstly i want to have correct index.

Comment: @Ishan You question was to get the table element and thats done. I want to look at the code below the table tag, ask another question, dont mess this 1 up